# Chess MVC UML diagram for Java chess game

Tags: java, model-view-controller, uml, game-development, chess

I have a school project of creating a game with Java, I chose to program chess. My teacher want us first to design the game by creating a UML design of all classes we think will be necessary for the game.

The problem is the wants it to be design with the MVC pattern, Model View Controller. I tried to design the UML

Here my diagram:

[image]

I'm also using observer pattern in order to communicate between the different parts.

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me and tell me how can I improve this diagram so
it follows the mvc pattern.  I tried handing my teacher diffrent UML designs but he is still not pleased

Here is an updated link to the uml diagram:
[click me](https://viewer.diagrams.net/?tags=%7B%7D&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=Copy%20of%20Untitled%20Diagram.drawio#R7V1Zd5s6F%2F01Xit9cBez4TF22jS3U9rkpjd9%2BRY2cswtNrmAM%2F36T0w2g8AgBAhbeWhtzCB0tqSjfbaORuJs%2FXLp6I%2Brr7YBrJHAGS8j8WIkCLwkKSr83z%2F0Gh3iJhMhPPTgmEZ0cH%2FgxnwD4cHowoetaQA3dZ5n25ZnPqYPLuzNBiy81DHdcezn9GlL20o%2F9FF%2FALkDNwvdyh%2F9ZRreKiqcMNkf%2FwTMh1X8ZF7Rwl%2FWenwyFx5wV7phPycOiR9G4syxbS%2F8tH6ZAcuvvrhawus%2BFvy6K5gDNl6VC6RL2b0Hy4V7J1%2BPRfD57Yc1G0vhXZ50axu98EhQLHi%2F6dKGt4Wl9l6jqlD%2B2%2FpFnaY%2BPUT%2FB5fMnewRw3xC3sO%2F%2Bfg5qrdzeMo8sEvJvQuLE9zKDWDj3whi7vEFeacIneHtYDWFd0w%2FBR4OitzWW7iP%2BqbKW6hywUsUVzUsenj3Jm%2FkgRdvrFvmwyYshwWWdU1O6IGcZW7AeJWoXEmG%2BJYHVJqqxpb4Q8au9J65s9pFBNkqmeuLPw%2BOvd0Y44Vt2U54R3NjeqZu4XUMRC%2Bh15YF3VjBYdoAQaTFGmBhO7pn2puxX4bw4RBKwAm%2FToOBv6iv5up3eoQhvMUd7JSDaENVbwE0cqUowCHCOrmbCqnSC0GtAN8P4eDPzyvTAzeP%2BsL%2F9Rk6jvDYylvDOrrg4ccn4HgmdMDOQ4tcePZj9OYf9bVp%2BY7kzN46JoDvxn0Dz%2F6PpmXNwjqHjxOX6gIsFn6r9Rz7D0j8MldlH5TxL7FHJ%2B8KnXSnIg%2FLLw94SRyK3KtLYK%2BB57zCU6Jfx4IsKuFFkbs7lng5cnef996jqMrRaauE6ygo8VE98lkfdk%2FYu3XwQ%2BTZ1fDyxEIvr6hdEXRhypoeVpvR1z4gNnP3MbwJwUOl%2FWT5mxN8wXoOL68WdAJ3JmwcWCNC1V4ZYyAtAlwfg8fJOnXMdaPCYl27bgN10JgbdkJuWOSHX%2Byc8MZe2UQU0z6ZzClSzieDw6iU98lUjmvJJROOjngr9ENm8ETHtiwfKQTZN8ZVMa6KcVWDsiXjqhhXxZwkOrgqlecybpGgcRXdIk2WmrtF%2F9w8PF38t30RF19%2Brj%2Fff7y4fNFipiphD2A8gJvoq%2B14K%2FvB3ujWh%2F3Radpi%2B3O%2B2L41Ajv9CzzvNYot61vPTlsxXcFaZMHodEkNztAd79wPJ8MjGztoqMGxj6b%2FfsGDwcaIzzBMfW1vjPBg%2BpTortADLTGjCzGziN5fV7%2F8%2Fv1p%2BeP789%2BfX%2B%2FFxWb52469R1iCB%2BCVnCeH5%2Fl1WAoKB1iwT3pKx7xRxg0uha%2BpvyZOeLTNjecm7nztH0h44JqQhpooRKjaQyW85x44u8JVwlJZJdHvYpPuo6t2yYVR5qmtO8bhXrhij1u%2FouoPc9ErL%2FVF%2Bhl3wDH0jd553S92%2Ffj%2BRHG5FEV%2FMro%2F1MBJGy9N2McFpfIf%2BOvq4vaTz2n79%2BJUDOPVGX97snJfDeWgp1wDflWhgbTypw9Xl59uK9uYtdveoFDPynPbtkAwa1uajutdW%2For9OS2zgancVZu8EdVhdcmgBiSp2FHKF%2FAj1FrkS8CjFYa0mq0mBYZrAHzFWhQkek5myAr9GnO3gUnEjQ3bSQFHShoZlWMt2tAbU23j4bugT0%2BnmzTOACGo%2BS3GHRqQwfOvoNx59w7Cxy0GfzXh1A4GNXHEIFhnqFq8KjSDSMAkHtrs16J8AyhyC5YSq3pYqVvHsAtdNQr2ailKfZQQoEYpvR72NnW8RnSXS3vJks4bhxt8KY3WEdflbDAK64thz0EDEQqweDJ4Nl%2Faei1Mn1Vwlosa7HYpWFKnlrVe%2FxKniVQ0EoeLvgbtaTkkWI1c6yuEDQur29WBZS8OT7YRMfz9vbiXEmXyvr8193F5te%2F334%2F%2FBxLfeh46itwQgHNNXBM%2BNrA8eFhbh4KZUH4gh2pomBHoEKwI0o5SIkpwU6FK%2BRI9NOqxGcw6StId96NJT5ZhrprqUDHFYWvzOA4Bf6lzjvsjxXlINHnsFPRF0F029JdF2fEbM0k%2FbskA9Lj3HiOP1LEl%2BN6xsdvTJI2ICGX2xnOe33sswNkBsoYKPQnFiHZ%2F9OusHSd2aZhnWeeVq8nTNkLznaK7VWUZKEds1ISfqSDdELjstUROHQtz67Wfma9QBGx%2BxfP9jVIJeockni0mQV0wDuiFcDaBF6boISInZruV%2FsJ3EGzGGn10AE4tEbJolsPQcVEPnI%2FBLhThdphKJh81YZfI4FeY5aZIXWKaQacoQEHuv4BbIIukYGGgaZib3PKoCl6ytx2DOAk8fKkO2fjcfL4u4LHykUk5mGkVn8qhtkbPZCgSzt1w74qctoy2s9OJYnMzO2a2e9dOjTz4KURxzkY9j3OlRjoZAa6gcCzdyvTVyWsxbIWi10aprWrVb1Ma9dW1ixeUieZXEYTJZ82S9XEvNqO50hkE0WmzZJk6vJmidqohbxZE67MkAdleHJehofMzqpRIcPjJT6znYAocWr7qjqZqeowVXWX%2BhpU3Gcq7ybUHIz7lVlREtNvwQ3FISvwydOaSW6CxEB%2B5xd84PEqvod9wk7DHgKzR7%2F2iBIXcosVcN0GWQyZRUhZ5Pzqf7tGopvxx6xrMHaB9335fe4CBzrjxGTRKDNW3hyjATGOPTI3Mkwj0ZbuefpidRaboO%2BIxolbwwADtwa2RKyozhtVZ5jhC5WipWo1doguAgxkC91mLV1Wy0NlH%2FrDJmNsSHn4c0OMip%2F3NMctfMEmzahddd%2FR4AVsDKJoISjhrJqLjIk4GyKx9%2BDV1HRnK7D489UfOoO5VIM0dHQnNjyajsN9Nr3F6jaROJr1Hazv6KHvCBMj3ngFbndVSNLUSTC9CtLUJe9Zw8r0VQnTq%2BDakrVYplchwk0wvcqoqV5F5LNbb2lxpp6EXEVRubxcRRMIqFXeHu%2B%2BXhu%2Fvr09%2FjVTbr5e%2FDG%2F3o8FtT%2B1yuGqz%2BhYeEEcEROyBJckpSzElC2xsQ5nmBKp0LaMeTnWTe1SRk0ifRRS3IK4g6ip6TtIiqSmyxkl%2BAqvzMCWxBZzHJPKYEpl%2FLXPh4eAit096Rl%2FrRhnqx4ZUmdTm5eIknWEvQh2bpUa%2Fh5%2B%2FKfjFPnEqR%2B6EZQCQjppS0OL02K4Lqm31mQTVe1oANczN8FEI92qUcakh1dtb9JNgB2jvOkmTI7Xfus01ObYIDnLHcygMmAmat4pK40vOA78x7NkcqlECh0s72Yg%2FBSDSS2YwNnfje1sA68XkSHi%2BPDR1HHtnYNGWjByV8nn%2BBh0c%2BpfKlavUdA25B5jW7lITQnIN5jc5bRjcQjooh1JrXS99CJp2MFHJhc4du%2BbluGHiC2ZXIDJBYj05EwuMGoqFxBEVcroBQRNyesF4i2nknqBSXt6AeXY9QJzy178GdVQC0jB1xfT%2B8c%2F970cfbuPbw0%2FX7wkv7xGXxooDPiKCgOZDoGBwAkZeYA4EVLZM1DX5PQyONdoolJ%2BjcxlmxnGJbLCt58LZNeJMIVDwRhWvMVWarEz0zhUnXticjPj3c4%2Bm%2FTaKaZw6Cd43UFIdLehAGe6v3yvjOgUhIU5j3YGjR4syDQWovGrcBA52%2B0jE0ArAL3PxzUZYgYywWZ4qRvvvAq7woCwze%2B4ckIIaUxt4fTECIN8g%2F5IYI24FRN0TY6w1o%2BPHD7dKmEBDcoNRMfwygIa1ACCBTRGLKAxOpqAhiRlVpmJqqrmAhqqgAhoyPFKSeIBDa2PeEYcLYg%2F36ciB%2BhoQZcxkOiM4hCIMkpGQGShDCKHoxkCHVEKXtLkNEB5VToQceBzUTqcawSZV0aF8YP8HbSJXHCDzlZbCiwWgRuL0J8xSYCeSNC%2BarC%2FNV8JMntpOq5XbYHsyVqy%2FSSsfptBbmMe0jiYy0xOfKaHRgMF1k7uxn3yzOkQING%2FTHggVmYcHOUGoqMZMg6OGkA0bbE0u2%2Bouu6FXSswOgpkR0qwBYxNVGSJCNsmCFmSgZPybNtE0PJsm6i1tTmeIvYnH84SZDt7xv5rijeTYqug7dfGXno7VvA9x2WYQVEZlXGD%2Fpdr4JjQSMAZNVYXi8NSF%2FNcFuqSrB3i4PLXCOqhazSh%2FJLGsl90m%2BlFcg9R47wmFO3%2B1%2Fvkb3skBt%2FSNHW9tsbzaueNrYPmQQmtLUhqLjcfL5VDPX8NL8tC6TXqRCm%2FoiVRvMiIaEwiOrEfWF%2FsWefz5BbmfbipyshmIcvcvLpObmnCYSF4Jf%2B6m6uvf385v736%2Fu0GfgvuwIWbJVPFytCh8e6pQbe5FyyF77Tvp%2FbS62msuyYJS0Y6DTdHxmJl2y4IEpFFe43O%2FC%2BnvN9FW%2FZEdxENdPJlxiEPHtdcb6G%2FDTrZ1Stbmv3mTYfTt9DWSxELJxEYzoZQXyzWQ3kHSdWw2%2FuIymI9TG%2Ft%2F8%2F01hSEg0hEgPjd9jI73k8VuVwESI1zxSQjQJIotBUB4nMG6S0C1EKoB6mc3lPPilRm3MPUs9QKpZznfyU1I9UXZC5zl7YFxhLjdTF53anprmC7oI7UxSba%2BtrCNVeRVT2hviBRPO8krp2lbbZFhzOPNjyRJkFOUpvIzn8a2lo2E6fcQHQ0XjYTpwYQTHXZwRybqS6Jqy5FlX%2BfXZopSXJ8LCm8VGWE8FIhILxELnOW%2Bpt105K2FbFmeZ%2B1VeK0UVJxyXHlq7EJKy7lipKydub%2FtSVlmppRQvqMUbHWK38DVVVy7YQXfeHr7i9T6LAOc3QDsmzJ23Ba5jG7hMldERkyIzIwiYzP2Bm6qKQx0PWbqFTnYX4myHKYWlDm4%2F%2FfhY5LVZcysXh5Ded8pdqHnpiVVl1cKm3fF4WVaUJVa7evruCECaxcGRvUWS2AtsENDYRxGQI3yNZWM5aPsXyM5WMsH2P5cHp0xvIRZ%2Fl4MbudzV4wk1TWcAhlDRGKD000KIxowCQafmwBaD8n2%2FHPNrP1WHUk6wsQJzzdpMMZQxueSIsgp5dgMgmqANq7001flbAJFK4t2QSKTaDYBKrrCRScBmUDyBI3yWskFPU9QiUhqGJbixOEk1%2BcsJdEcFwskQglEZLUqSRi0tFSB0Q2dl%2F8UUUiUD9T1cFs8aN2kuRMGDWASQ38tO0%2FeF4%2FlcwAun6ZBoGw%2F0il7Xup6Ez7qVq1ffUDjBFijBDiaYwO6rs09FII9FUJo4MID%2Ben1GJZ%2FgoSpBHLX9GYJOKFiZBbJMBxiBzmXKdLafheMljseJkR2zLQHsf6i%2FbZIZ7LskNVt9qrzQ7lkm7wk0lqW8BKeTr4A5eUvFG7HJTKOCjcdTCboPTHw0L1thoiW5FVXcO%2BIMHoCEZHIJ922gk9Bo0NtqCDEVCMgGIEFCOgGAHFCCiKCShUMhdOFPP8U6xH6madh4iaSGcJqRwxkzBJ2n7pupMOGmfPEyl1pUmFRmmbxoHmeK8l%2FvgMz7Lb2a1utpHcJov5W9Vmh0gnIJlUwIuzstfzrXu4OVdtg01x9PFjsA8SoYaspFkyXlPyLLKKWKylEmjD0qXs3oPlwr2Tr8ci%2BPz2w5qNi5dqdb6FFob7VN%2BZOAISbrYCrjuDJzu2ZfW5ZxpOZVI1kyIsXqvrs0ePr7X92tjfLearbQC%2FZa9fo08EZuM9vlIA6DsT9sb%2BK%2FkfDqI6%2BarZBnGWqCJfM%2Bjf8F3pq9eoNzbFbcAqYrxdE5J9pW8MCyJh64JrB0LkLPj44QmE%2FCTmdlx10DKQ2TLDVhNs%2FQQW0F1ABl0MS6eHJV%2BYfmungyesc2KAwgbU9tHQPXB2yt0QXRMNqjDcNzxZfGIw8OzdyvRVCWuxrMWSLQ2BWCOLKKJwyCKKhYGIiZxJeyBzcSb9RCSC5%2BJcCMlYhCIJLQUjtKEIc6t2suUcfkh5dtHjDcMNKeitbAf2gsme6kl3zsbj5PGai8ILh7g6szxitH29wE3Fju5ILYYTX8AwbmS0XKQNmq5y4K3yiFbaLe3rhhcOo5kuaXjrrWokTC8d07jWoYfk99q6Yxyo68ZBUoyQ4dTv58%2BmYen8gJTfF%2BBo49tz7fEDoQ0FwNR5%2BT11aLXwZJjuo6W%2FBohCkXxdywDY%2FJpII2Tz68alYYpdNr%2BmYX6tZdOySxqfn16r8frd5Oxaji8lvlxczItzO1wtvlshfj9KLBCvuVq8pbXh2SXo7a0WV7qRGY95biIWrK0mn0tQzZJJxNdxO%2Ba%2Fm2dLehMnFzf8pfLhu3P%2B1xghNm8fzwkEamjw4ORHSEDUMPW1vTFyKN1jcFI5nyWyGxAilu3gFp8yaaw26r2EwZCDpJ2CxoLh73MXOE9YSmH0uxR7fv2yDfradxA2c%2Fexkp%2FTcEKE4%2BUW3avGDDP3WFnCI4aqP7IFqzaYUudfF80acZwC%2F0qAYuW%2FwZENOMFkPD6cvgSX6vD7m0a1UH8e3YV5icwjW8V%2B%2Fckr3U2xC36pWD7WrCOtc3RApAPjxBgndtLw7N3K9FUJa7GsxTIW%2ByBAGYtNM4stZ1lsUVURSU8VxHp1UWgr6Wl8425pP3IJTPf8XpMcppM0JShVpgTLkgB0zwgWMcqylgGeFm9XQ5q8VrOBGi5KtVCYtvTQFY3JbjTse4nedAz7Iu67BPnVyfAyxWkS%2BWUtpG3k85ySSeMiKVymJy3ICFMX%2BUoci9o%2FSVVLkZ%2B%2FYhIFmVoN8%2FQI%2FAJ4axnYzi178ScH2gxGDd1dBSXiywCbBGJpGKT1REVyJuGUJGe7YEJARDzpQLJpReLKr2gMROSefNKEOiRK6ojYnnyHA4%2FBtnyV%2Blp0%2FVV1M6SO3IxdurRd3FptK0aef5RCeLu90iqnP2jafEVF0AJIMgODie8RTmPEAoOIwCDYbNcgJGVGLDTYKDTYPLMSixgS6Qwq0L9qQel%2Bfbq6%2FYABdlLc7AlW%2BfTL%2BewzsSqnLxbLYinIoYHFUugoDb1Wpq9KWItlLZZFPw8ClEU%2FaY5%2BjgVJzdJDcsSnJMKfsoAKf0pSMRtVEP6EXx3bt%2FueAIK1uQpTBYgf%2Fg8%3D)

Comment: Did the instructor give you any more specific feedback than, "not good enough?" That diagram is more detailed than I have ever done in almost 25 years of professional programming and design. Seems "good" enough to me.

Comment: he says some actions are not fit to the controller package and some doesnt fit the model.

Comment: for example he says that the moveTo function supposed to be in the model not the controller, and in MOVE class should only be 2 points not 4 integers. overall he said I lack understanding of the mvc pattern and need to learn more and improve it

Comment: I don't have an answer for you. I can only express my sympathy for you because it sounds like the instructor is focusing too much on an outdated methodology, called Big Design Up Front (BDUF) that isn't in the best interest of young programmers to learn.

Comment: Off-topic: The UML diagram is fuzzy to me. It's hard for me to read. I suspect it is the same for others with poor eyesight. Is is possible to show us an SVG or other format that will show a sharp image when we zoom in or zoom out?

Comment: thanks for the comment, I uploaded a link in the title

Comment: @אביבניר I've edited your question, adding the remarks of your professor that you've added in the comments.  This is important information to narrow down the question which would otherwise be too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing exactly the criticism of your teachers, I'll go through your diagram and highlight the main points of concerns.

### UML semantics and syntax

`Player` does probably not inherit from the `GameModel` contrary to what is documented in  the diagram. Consider removing the hollow arrow head, and make the relation a simple association.

You can remove all the white diamonds of shared aggregation:  the UML specification does not define any semantic for it, and it de facto means the same as when using simple associations.  Always prefer simplicity ;-)

The class syntax should be respected, with a compartment for the class name, a compartment for attributes and a compartment for operations.  The <> and enum stereotypes should be above the name of the type.

### On using patterns

Unfortunately, you diagram does not show how the Observer pattern allows to decouple the related classes.  You should define the Observer and the Subject interface outside the MVC, and show with interface realization, which class implements the observer but also which one implements the subject.

This being said, in MVC, the View is in general an observer of the Model. It is not very common to make the controller an observer of the Model, unless you want to have some state dependent menus where some options are greyed depending on the state of the model).

### On the MVC

There are many variants of the MVC and many confusions with similar patterns. Hence, I'll refer to the [original MVC](https://folk.universitetetioslo.no/trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html) definition:

- **Model** is everything about game logic, including a move, because moving pieces is part of the game model.
- **Controler** is everything related to processing user input.  So processing mouse or keyboard events does belong there. Auxiliary function to transform the user input into commands/requests to the model and meaningful arguments to provide to the Model should also belong to the controller.  But the commands themselves (e.g. move pieces in the game) should belong to Model classes. Because it's the model that knows the rules of the game, and if the model doesn't keep track of the move, the game's state wiuld be inacurate.
- **View** is everything about rendering the model in a certain way for the user.

### Special topics

The human player and the AI player are both special kinds of players.  The player state (color,  whose turn it is, time spent on a move, ...) belongs to the model.  The human player input of the user is in most of the case about commands (moves) performed by the one of the two player in the Model.

Th AI should be part of the model, since it changes the state of the game on its own and doesn't fit on its own to view or controller.

Answer (score 2):

You have a good start here! Try thinking abstractly, when designing. For each class, ask what it should know (attributes) and what it should be able to do (methods). What should a Piece be able to do? (e.g., move to another space, report it's position, report if it is in jeopardy). Obviously, each type of Piece has different rules. Think of the controller as sort of a referee...it keeps track of whose move it is, tells you if the move is valid, tells when you're in check/checkmate.

Comment: I agree that it's a good start and what you say makes sense. However the controller cannot be a referee nor know about game logic in an MVC architecture. This is contrary to the goals of the architecture, which is to separate the game/buisness logic inthe model from the user and system interactions in the controller and the view.